# Binary logarithm inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $i$ and $n$ be two integers $>1$. Assume that

$$
i < \log_2(1+i)^n.
$$
Under this assumption, does the inequality
$$
i+1 \leq \log_2(1+i)^n
$$
hold? If so, how can we prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implication is not always true.  For example, if $i=4$ and $n=2$ then
$$2^i<(1+i)^n\quad\hbox{so}\quad i<\log_2(1+i)^n$$
but
$$2^{i+1}>(1+i)^n\quad\hbox{so}\quad i+1\not\le\log_2(1+i)^n\ .$$

There are many other examples too.